# Most angular2 way of adding received info to the view

Tags: angular, components

**I Have read tutorials about dinamically adding angular2 components but did not understand them, I need specifics for this situation**

So basically I have the `main.component.ts` which holds all the current view of my app. In this view there is the following html:

```
(...)
<StackLayout id="cars-wrapper">
      <!-- FILL IN HERE -->
</StackLayout>
(...)
```

What I'd like to do is - **after receiving info from the server** - to populate "FILL IN HERE" with components related to the car view (`car.component.ts`) which has the following template

```
<Label [text]="car.name"></Label>
<Label [text]="car.color"></Label>
```

In `main.component.ts` I have a method that calls a service that calls `getCarsInfoFromServer()`. This method returns to `main.component.ts` via  a `.subscribe()` call.

As so, I'm left in `main.component.ts` with a json variable from the callback that contains info on the cars (`car_info`).

What I'd like to do is in theory analogous to the following:

```
for(var i = 0; i < car_info.length; i++){

   var car_name = car_info[i].name;
   var car_color = car_info[i].name;

   addCarInfoComponentToTheMainView(car_name, car_color)

}
```

Though I want to make sure I do this the most correct, speed efficient, versatile and cross-platform angular2 way.

So, how exactly should I go about it?

Thank you very much for your help :)

---

### **EDIT**

How my actual code is:

**roads.component.ts** (the main component)

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'roads',
  templateUrl: 'roads.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['roads.component.css']
})

export class RoadComponent {

    roads: any[];

     constructor() {

          // Hard testing, let component render
          setTimeout(()=>{
                this.initView();
                var to_push = {width:20, name:"a road name"};
                this.roads.push(to_push);
          },1000);

      }  

}
```

**roads.component.tns.html**

```
<StackLayout class="p-10">
      <Label [text]="'Inside'"></Label>
      <Label [text]="'Inside'"></Label>
      <Label [text]="'Inside'"></Label>
      <Label [text]="'Inside'"></Label>
      <Label [text]="'Inside'"></Label>
      <Label [text]="'Inside'"></Label>
      <Label [text]="'Inside'"></Label>
      <Label [text]="'Inside'"></Label>
      <Label [text]="'Inside'"></Label>
      <Label [text]="'Inside'"></Label>
      <Label [text]="'Inside'"></Label>
      <Label [text]="'Inside'"></Label>
      <Label [text]="'Inside'"></Label>

      <!-- ^ "INSIDE" labels appear, the labels below in the ng-container (Test and Test2) do not. 
The loop is "not activated" because the Test and Test2 labels are not activated when the roads array is populated -->

        <ng-container *ngFor="let road of roads; let idx=index">
          <roadinfo-element-component [roadInfo]="road"></roadinfo-element-component>
          <Label [text]="'Test'"></Label>
          <Label [text]="'Test2'"></Label>

        </ng-container>

  <StackLayout orientation="vertical" class="input-field">

  </StackLayout>

</StackLayout>
```

**roadinfo-element-component**

```
import { RoadInfoElement } from '../../interfaces/RoadInfo-element';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'roadinfo-element-component',
    templateUrl: './roadinfo-element.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./roadinfo-element.component.scss']
})
export class RoadInfoElementComponent {

    @Input() roadInfo: RoadInfoElement;

}
```

**RoadInfoElement** (interface)

```
export interface RoadInfoElement {

    width: Number;

    name: string;

}
```

**roadinfo.component.tns.html**

```
<Label text="{{roadInfo.name}}"></Label>
<Label text="{{roadInfo.width}}'"></Label>
```

**roads.common.ts**

```
export const SHARED_MODULES: any[] = [
    SharedModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(<any>RoadRoutes),
    TranslateModule.forChild()
];

export const COMPONENT_DECLARATIONS: any[] = [
    RoadsComponent,
    RoadInfoElementComponent
];
```

Where `SHARED_MODULES` and `COMPONENT_DECLARATIONS` go to the correct angular modules.

Comment: `<car-component *ngFor="let car of allCars" [carInfo]="car"></car-component>` should do what you want. Where `allCars` is an array in the component that contains an item per car you want to show and `carInfo` is `@Input() carInfo:any;` inside `class CarComponent {}`. So you don't add a `car-component` to the view using code, instead you let Angular directives like `*ngFor` do it and control it by modifying data.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer would you mind putting that through an answer? Not really understanding with this formatting (and I can select you as correct) ty!! :)

Comment: I guess your `SHARED_MODULES` is missing `CommonModule`. You should get an error in the browser console for that though.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer would that be the only problem with the code provided? I'm using the native-angular-seed and in other components outside the app.component the CommonModule is never included... are you absolutely sure nothing else is wrong? :/

Comment: Have you even tried it? `*ngFor` is as simple as you have it. I can't tell without running the code if `roads` ever gets values added. You didn't provide any feedback if you get errors in the browser console. "in other components outside the app.component the CommonModule is never included" I can't make any sense of this part of your comment. `CommonModule` is required in every module where you use `*ngIf`, `*ngFor`, ....

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer wait holy sh*t it worked

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer So basically it worked while I open the roads component and immediately insert info into the array. But want I want is to begin the app in a different component, login and route to the roads component. Only then populate the array. It seems like it fails that way but let me make sure first

Comment: You accepted my answer. Does this mean you could make it work with the router as well?

Comment: Yes yes! Tbh I tried again removing "; let idx=index" in the *ngFor loop part and it seems to have worked!! Thank you so much @GünterZöchbauer, you are amazing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Angular you don't add a `<car-component>` to the view using code, instead you let Angular directives like `*ngFor` do it and control it by modifying data.

**some-component.ts**

```ts
@Component({ 
  selector: 'some-component',
  template: 'some-component.html',
})
export class MyComponent {
  carInfo:any[];

  constructor() {
    // get car_info from somewhere
    this.carInfo = loadCarInfo();
  }

  addNewCar() {
    this.carInfo.push({name: 'new car', color: 'black'});
  }

  deleteCar(index:number) {
    this.carInfo.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

**some-cmponent.html**

```ts
<ng-container *ngFor="let car of carInfo; let idx=index">
  <car-component [carInfo]="car"></car-component>
  <button (click)="deleteCar(idx)">delete</button>
</ng-container>
<button (click)="addNewCar()">add new car</button>
```

**car-component.ts**

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'car-component',
  template: 'car-component.html'
})
export class CarComponent {
  @Input() carInfo:any;
}
```

**car-component.html**

```ts
<div>name: {{carInfo.name}}</div> 
<div>name: {{carInfo.color}}</div>
```

Comment: This is fantastic Gunter!!! I think I understood it completely!

One more question though: imagine each car has a component called "people  inside". It's not a property but a component. Should the **CarComponent** have @input() PeopleInsde[] and then I push it too? How could I push people inside but from the main component?

Comment: If `carInfo.peopleInside` contains the info, you can just repeat above pattern inside `<car-component>` with `<person-component *ngFor="let person of carInfo.peopleInside` [person]="person"></person-component>`

Comment: Hmm this is actually not working for me, no errors are thrown... is something missing in the code? Does main_component carInfo[] need to have "@input"?

Comment: Did you add all components to `declarations: [...]` in `@NgModule(...)`

Comment: Do I need to? All of them? Even those that are added dinamically and inserted into the main components?

Comment: Yes all, except you import a module instead that lists the components in `declarations: [...]` (and `exports: [...]`)

Comment: Hello Gunter :) thank you for your help but it is still not working... I've put `car-component` and `some-component` inside my declarations and exported but it is not working. My xml has the selector of car-component, inside a ngFor* for the carInfo array but nothing happens when I push an object with the properties of the template to the carInfo array (literally nothing happens, no errors, no nothing...). I know the components were imported because I had syntax errors that I fixed but for example not even inserting multiple "<Label [text]="'TEXT'"></Label>" inside the ngFor loop activated it

Comment: Please add the code you have to your question, or create a Plunker so I can check.

Comment: Gunter sorry I edited your answer and not my question on mistake. Either way please do check the edit on my question or your answer depending wether StackOverflow will allow me to edit again.

I really can't understand why this is not working and I really need this fixed...